# Java board game

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically I'm creating a board game in java and have managed to create cells, using arrays, to look like a 10x10 grid.  Now I've numbered them they go from left to right top to bottom (as pic)
I'm creating a game similar to a snakes and ladders game but having its own twist.

**Question is:** How to create a zigzag board similar to a snakes & ladder board?

That's how it currently looks: [image]

Code below is of whats required to create arrays and print them and number them.

---

*Object named Game:*

```
private Cell[][] cell =  new Cell[10][10];

public Game(String nameIt)
{
     super(nameIt);
     JPanel x = new JPanel(); 

 x.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 2, 2)); 
 for (int r = 0; ir< 10; r++) 
  for (int c= 0; c < 10; c++) 

  x.add(cell[r][c] = new Cell(r, c, this));

}
```

*Object named cell:*

```
private int row;
private int col;
private int cellNum;
static int count = 0;


public Cell(int row, int column, Game guy) 
{

    this.ro = row;
    this.col = column;
    this.parent = guy;

    count = count+1;
    cellNum = count;

    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1));   // Set cell's border
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics p) 
{
    super.paintComponent(p);

    p.drawString(String.valueOf(" " + cellNo), 24, 24);

}
```

Comment: You should not duplicate your questions on SO. This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342762/board-game-in-java

Comment: Someone asked him to create a duplicate after the other question was closed for being too broad.

Comment: The original question has just been re-opened. I think the OP was asked to re-write the question and so has posted a new one, so go easy ;-)

Comment: sorry for being a newbings lol but i have deleted the other question :) @axiopisty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I won't write the exact code for you, but I'll show you an example of how to do it with a regular 2D array. I only have a C++ compiler available right now, but it should be clear enough:

So basically you need to cycle through rows **from end to start**. That's why the first, outer loop you're going from 9 to 0. This will start at bottom row and finish at the top row, thus reversing.

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {

    // now the trick to making a "zig-zag" is to alternate between two ways
    // of printing out each row. if i is even, you print out from right to left

    if (i % 2)
        for (int j = 9; j >= 0; j--)
            cout << numbers[i][j] << "\t";

    // and if i is odd, you print it out from left to right
    else
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            cout << numbers[i][j] << "\t";

    cout << endl;

}
```

Result: [image]

Comment: I'm somewhat a newbie to programming...could you expand more on what you mean "cout << numbers[i][j]" because the numbers array I don't have in the cell class but I could use the variables instead

It's the operators that I don't understand lol

Comment: @YouSof `cout << numbers[i][j]` prints out the element at row index `i` and column index `j`. So, for example, based on your image (http://i.stack.imgur.com/x4551.png), the element in row number 4 and column number 8 is 49. it is equivalent to `System.out.print(numbers[i][j]);` in Java

Comment: still doesn't work, the way I've programmed it, is that each time a cell is created it prints the cell number, within the cell class. The way that you've told me to do it is within the Game class and I don't have a paint method as such in there and don't wish to keep it there either...is there any other way of going about this?

Comment: I've posted the loop i created in the question above have a look

Comment: @YouSof that loop is not supposed to be inside your `Cell` class. What you want to do, is to have that loop when you're **displaying** your cells...

I suggest you perform this exercise first: without any `Cell` classes, just do what I did, in your main. Make a 2D array, fill it up with numbers from 1 to 100, and display it using a zigzag method that I posted. Only after you know how it works on low level, you should try to implement a `Cell`

Comment: i wanted something inside the cell class so i could print it out to display which cell it was if that makes sense lol