# How to change array to print in specific way in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I currently have a game that prints out a snakes-and-ladders board. However, the snakes and ladders pictures don't align properly since the array has to be adjusted.

My current array is this:

```
 for (int i = 63 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        a [i] = new JLabel (createImageIcon (i+".jpg"));
        g.add (a [i]);
    }
```

However, the pictures don't match up and I want the array to look like http://www.uni-play.co.uk/product/1-64-snakes-ladders-2/

So every second row has to be reversed. (Instead of 56, 55,, 54, 53, 53, 51, 50, 49 as it currently prints it must be the other way.)

What would the array look like to print this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exact same question, with answer, here: [Java board game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343374/java-board-game)

Comment: easy solution will be printing row by row and using mod operator. Like                        (for (int i = 0; i < number of rows; i++ ){ if(i %2 == 0) { your loop here }else{ your reverse loop here } };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that needs help in the future:

```
 for (int rownum = 7 ; rownum >= 0 ; rownum--)
    {
    int number = rownum*8;
        if (rownum % 2 != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 7 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
            {
                a [i+number] = new JLabel (createImageIcon ((i+number) + ".jpg"));
                g.add (a [i+number]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {   
                a [i+number] = new JLabel (createImageIcon ((i+number) + ".jpg"));
                g.add (a [i+number]);
            }
        }
        }
```